# Flutter position Text in floating-action-button?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there anyway that I can position text in the extended floating action button.

For example I want to position text at the right corner of the button.

How can I do this ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is your issue resolved? :)

Answer (score 3):

The FloatingActionButton in the Scaffold accepts a widget. So you can do something like this:

```
floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton.extended(
            // label cannot be null, but it's a widget
            // so it can be an empty container or something else
            label: Text("button"), 
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          Positioned(right: 0.0, top: 0.0, child: Text("text")),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap Text Widget with Padding or set padding to floating action button.